# UWP JS App Ignores style setting webkitTextSecurity

Tags: uwp, styles, textarea

I have a Javascript based App that runs as a MacOS App, an IOS App, an Android App, a Chrome Packaged App and as a Windows UWP JS App. It have also tested it using Chrome, Safari and Edge browsers.

In all of these except the UWP JS App, I can prompt for password entry using a text area with style.webkitTextSecurity set to "disc" to hide the user's password entry from any prying eyes.

In the UWP JS app, this style setting is ignored. When running the code in VS17 debugger and examining the text area element in the DOM, this style setting is not listed. I cannot set it through the javascript console, even though it comes up as one of the options when you start to type the field on the command line.

textSecurity and msTextSecurity do not work either.

Am I mistaken? I thought UWP JS Apps used the Edge Browser to run them and I always through Edge was Chromium based.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to use a text area element and I used an input element instead with type set to password.